# Explain why "a small system in contact with a reservoir explores all possible states"?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

A snippet out of the lecture notes from my first course in statistical mechanics:

> For a simple example, consider a single spin-half particle with spin down in system 1
> coming into thermal contact with system 2 containing nine spin-half particle all
> spin up. After thermal contact, the particle in system one is most likely to be
> found with spin up; i.e., like one of the particles in the large system. Indeed, after
> thermal contact, there are a total of 10 states with one spin down and the remaining
> 9 up, and the probability to find the particle in system 1 with spin up is 9/10 ≈ 1. On
> the other hand, suppose system 2 has five spin up and four spin down particles
> before thermal contact. Now the particle in system 1 is equally likely to be found
> with spin up or spin down. The lesson is that a small system, such as a single particle,
> would tend to look like a set of small systems, or the single particle explores the
> states of each one of the particles in the larger system in thermal contact. Therefore,
> a much smaller system, such as a single particle, in thermal contact with a large
> system exhibit significant fluctuations.

My questions are

1. What exactly is meant by "the single particle explores the states of each one of the particles in the larger system in thermal contact"?
2. What does "exhibit significant fluctuations" mean? What is changing, and is it changing over time (ie every second)? What is causing this change from second-to-second/why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Without going into statistical dynamics, we can describe the states of particles as points in *phase space*. In thermodynamics, this is the joint space of positions and momenta.
Think in 1 dimension: the phase space of ONE particle would be a 2-d plane with $x$ and $p_x$ as its axes. Add a second particle and you have a 4-d space and so on. In 3-d (usually one leaves time out in classical mechanics, so no 4-d for you) these spaces become bigger by a factor of three.

The *microscopic state* of the system is then entirely determined by a point in phase space, which encodes all positions and momenta of particles.
*Macroscopic states* are also indeed determined by that point too, but not in a inique way.
You can swap particles, make one move slightly faster at another's expense, rotate the system etc. all while changing the microstate, yet keeping the same macrostate. Just think of gas in a balloon: without perturbations, the pressure, temperature and volume stay the same, yet no particle is at rest inside of it, hence changing its phase space configuration.
By changing these small variables, we say the system "explores" phase space.
A system with very little available configurations (maybe the box is small, so position space is restricted) will indeed explore them all faster than a system with many more.

On a macroscopic scale, one can use intuitive thermodynamics: have an ideal gas at equilibrium in a small piston chamber free to expand/contract (system $A$). Putting this in contact with a huge, really hot heat sink (system $B$) will surely disturb such equilibrium. Gas molecules in $A$ will start wizzing around and bumping into each other fairly violently, but the ones in $B$ will not do so. This is because there are many more particles to share energy with and many more dimensions of phase space to explore.
While the interaction is going on, particles in $B$ will not have moved much from their initial positions and momentum values except for statistical fluctuation, but particles in $A$, which is smaller and by definition has a smaller phase space, will have explored it thoroughly. Because phase space is *connected* (all points are allowed), it is most probable that at a certain time the microstate of $A$ coincided with one of $B$s, but not vice versa, and the "fluctuations" in $B$ are much less significant.

Super-simplified: more space=more possibilities, hence each one is less likely to happen in the span of the interaction.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the total number of spin up minus spin down is conserved by the microscopic Hamiltonian.

It means that the single particle you are scrutinising will be changing its own value of spin, by swapping with the rest, all the time. Somewhat as if living vicariously.

If you look at the single particle v.s. the rest, half-half case the single particle violently fluctuates from all up to all down and vice-versa, whereas the 9-particle system only fluctuates from 5u4d to 4u5d, which are small differences on average.

It is a silly thing, really.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. What exactly is meant by "the single particle explores the states of each one of the particles in the larger system in thermal contact"?

This is not a proof, but an *assumption* called [*ergodicity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodicity), on which many formulations of statistical mechanics are built (although there are formulations that avoid this assumption.) The claim is that, if we observe the system for some time, allowing it evolve in time according to its laws of motion, it will visit all the possible configurations, spending approximately the same time in each of them. Since our observation/experiment always lasts some time, we observe time averages of quantities, but given the assumption in the previous sentence, we can replace time averaging by averaging over (infinitely) many systems starting from different initial conditions and observed simultaneously. We can then use the usual probability theory for developing the statistical mechanics.

This assumption is known to hold in many cases. We also know of many situations where it doesn't hold - notably in the materials exhibiting phase transitions. E.g., the magnetization of a ferromagnet should, in principle, explore all the possible directions. However, in practice we would have to wait for a very long time (comparable to the lifetime of the universe) to see it reverse its direction spontaneously.

> 2. What does "exhibit significant fluctuations" mean? What is changing, and is it changing over time (ie every second)? What is causing this change from second-to-second/why does it happen?

Interactions with the environment, which is in constant motion.

Answer (score 0):

The gist of the quoted passage is that small systems exhibit larger fluctuations. When two systems are brought into thermal contact, energy is redistributed between them while its total value stays constant. Even at a equilibrium, some amount $\Delta E$ is exchanged between the two systems with equal probability in either direction. We view this as a "fluctuation" of the instantaneous energy of each system, i.e., $E_1 = \bar E_1 + \Delta E$ and $E_2 = \bar E_2 - \Delta E$, where $\bar E_1$ and $E_2$ are the mean egies at equilibrium. If $E_1<\bar E_2$, the same $\Delta E$ represents a larger percent fluctuation for the smaller system.